# Python regexp with optional parameters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write my own markdown extension and for videos I want user be able to provide optional values for width and height. Available formats of markdown is following:

```
http:/vimeo.com/456456456[width,height]
http:/vimeo.com/456456456
http:/vimeo.com/456456456[,height]
http:/vimeo.com/456456456[width,]
```

I have not questions with first part, but only with last - width and height. My current regex looks like:

```
rx = r'([^(]|^)(http|https)://(?:www.|)vimeo\.com/(?P<vimeoid>\d+)(?:\[(?P<width>\d+|),\s*,\s*(?P<height>\d+|)\]|)\S*'
```

Actually interesting only last part of it: `(?:\[(?P<width>\d+|),\s*,\s*(?P<height>\d+|)\]|)`. It is working fine if I provide values for width and height. But if I omitting it or omitting entire bracket part (it should be ok) my code still returns captured groups for `width` and `height` with values `None`. That is not what I want.

I want if used does not provided width or height or provided empty brackets or not provided it at all then groups for width and height does not evaluates.

**UPD:** Maybe it is side effect of python regular expression - to evaluates named groups always, I am not sure.

Comment: Will there be literal `[` and `]` in the URLs?

Comment: Nope, I suppose that chars [] not found in URL.

Comment: In that case pls provide some real examples of the URL.

Comment: It is real URL, which user can put to markdown editor. But [] is not part of initial URL, if you asked about it.

Answer (score 3):

Make the group itself optional instead of what it contains:

```
...(?:\[(?P<width>\d+)?\s*,\s*(?P<height>\d+)?\])?
```

Also `?` is generally more readable than an empty alternative (and potentially more efficient).

Now, if you omit either `width`, then `m.group(width)` will be `None` (and similarly for `height`). Note that there is no way to get rid of that `None`. When `re` applies a regular expression, it will initialize all values that correspond to a group in the pattern (that is, all numbered groups and all named groups that are in the pattern, *will* be defined in `.group()`). The distinction between groups that participate in the match and those that don't is whether they yield a string (possibly an empty one) or whether they are `None`. That's how it is.

Note that this pattern also allows for `[,]` as a synonym of omitting the brackets altogether.

Comment: I tried this regex already. It still assing width and height to None.

Comment: @AlexG.P. you won't get rid of that. That's how all matching functions in the `re` module work. What's wrong with checking for `None`?

Comment: @AlexG.P. the alternative is writing your own version of `re`. Good luck doing that with 2 lines ;)